# How to declare value (laravel 5.2)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm newbie here. I have a problem regarding to declare the value when the user input symptom that doesnt have in database ? I want to display message like "The symptom is doesnt match with the database"

[search.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn7dR.png)

[search bar img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLISz.png)

Comment: could you also show us the controller that handles this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you just want to notify the user that there are no results for their query. In that case you should add an `if` statement before the `foreach`, so it will be something like this:

```
@if(count($articles) > 0)
    @foreach($articles as $articles)
    ...
    @endforeach
@else
    <h1>The symptom doesn't match with the database</h1>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix blade syntac with PHP. Don't use

```
<?php if (...) ?>
```

because you can use

```
@if (...)
```

About declaring value it's really hard to guess what you want to achieve but first, you should not put images but put your code and explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry about that , i want to find the data from the database from the search bar but the problem is the data is not exist from database , So how to know the pass data from controller into view. Because i've use dd but i still cant find the pass data.